# "Move focus to the menu bar" shortcut does not work in Sonoma?

Tags: macos, keyboard, menu-bar

Ever since upgrading to Sonoma I have not been able to access the Menu bar.  I did change the shortcut long ago - and it had been working through various versions of macOS over the past decade.

Here is the current setting - <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>:

[image]

I have also tried various other keyboard combinations: none are working anymore. Any ideas why this is happening and if there are any workarounds?

*Update* I have tried a number of additional shortcuts. *Nothing* works. This used to work on Preview, Microsoft Word, PyCharm, Chrome .. none of them work.

Note also: This problem has persisted through every version of Sonoma that has been installed on this computer. It had worked in Ventura on this same computer.

Did Apple break this feature?

Comment: This may be solvable by finding and deleting the preference file that's responsible. You'll probably want a backup of the file so that you can re-add your other shortcuts in bulk. Much more detail in [Preferences, permissions and problem-solving](https://eclecticlight.co/2023/08/03/preferences-permissions-and-problem-solving/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found no definitive supporting documentation that this is indeed a bug but given that the problem didn’t exist in Ventura but manifested in Sonoma, it’s not unreasonable to believe that Apple broke something.

See this [Mac Rumors forum pos](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/sonoma-fixed-a-years-long-menu-bar-graphics-bug.2413768/)t we they were apparently tweaking things on the Manu Bar early on.

The best thing to do is submit feedback to Apple:  https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

Comment: Thanks, i'll wait to see if anyone has anything more specific before awarding

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a correct answer but I can confirm this shortcut works fine on  M1 Macbook Pro MacOS 14.4.

The only thing I may try is [Reset NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) (for Intel CPU Mac).

Comment: NVRAM has absolutely nothing to do with the menu bar.  NVRAM holds to preboot environment *before* macOS loads.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).